# Is there any possible way to take user input in the case of enum datatype

Tags: c

So this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    enum Month
    {
        January,
        February,
        March,
        April,
        May,
        June,
        July,
        August,
        September,
        October,
        November,
        December
    };
    char m1, m2;
    enum Month Month1, Month2;
    printf("Enter the first month: ");
    scanf("%s", &m1);
    printf("\nEnter the second month: ");
    scanf(" %s", &m2);
```

So here I took user input in string variable and then I tried typecasting but it didn't work.

```
    Month1 = (enum)m1;
    Month2 = enum m2;
    printf("Difference between 2 months in a year is : %d month.\n", Month2 - Month1);
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `enum`s are pretty much just named integers in C.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I thought typecasting would do the job.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &m1);` You cannot read a string into a single character.

Comment: You need to understand that C is a much lower-level language than Java or C#, for example,  and nothing like that happens automatically for you, like looking up an enum value based on its string name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast a string into an enum constant name to get that enum constant. What you're really doing is coercing the address of the string as the enum index, which is undefined behavior.

You could write a function to map it:

```
enum Month fromString (char *str)
{
    if(strcmp(str, "January") == 0)
    { 
        return January;
    }
    // and so on..
}
```

Comment: ```declaration is incompatible with previous "fromString" ```

Comment: @RawNewton name it something else.

Answer (score 1):

`enum` as well as variable names exist for the sole purpose of the programmer. The user doesn't know about them and shouldn't concern themselves with them. Similarly, the compiler will drop all named items in the final binary executable.

Therefore it doesn't make any sense to take an enum as an input, since enum is just a way for the programmer to easier keep track of numbers used in their own program. It fills no other purpose.

What you should do instead is to take the input as a proper string, then check it against a list of strings using `strcmp`.